# windows phone emulator was not able to connect to the windows phone operating system

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

It was working fine yesterday. Today, morning I just execute the project then I see the pop up error "windows phone emulator was not able to connect to the windows phone operating system; my be some functionality disabled".
Hyper-V is on and simulator of windows metro app is running well. Please suggest some solution

Comment: You may have to give more details. For example did you change any settings for the emulator?

Comment: No I did not do any change

Comment: check your network adapter settings..may be virtual switch for emulator be disabled..

Comment: simulator of windows metro app is running fine

Comment: okay, thank you @tanujkumarsharma I enabled switches in adapter settings and its working fine